# VBA to copy all sheets from multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, getopenfilename

I'm trying to make a VBA that would open multiple workbooks ( only one also), copy all their sheets in another workbook. I want to make my code functional directly from PersonalWorkbook so that i can use it in any new workbook that i want.

I know it's not a lot, but i got stucked with these incomplete versions (second one is not working as intended at all)...

```
Sub conso()
Dim folderpath As String
Dim file As String
Dim i As Long

folderpath = InputBox("Please paste the folder path", "Choose Folder") & "\"
file = Dir(folderpath)

Do While file <> ""
    Workbooks.Open folderpath & file
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        'ActiveSheet.Name = Right(Left(file, Len(file) - 5), Len(Left(file, Len(file) - 5)) - InStr(1, Left(file, Len(file) - 5), "("))
        'ActiveSheet.Name = file
        ActiveSheet.Name = Left(file, InStr(file, ".") - 1)
        Workbooks(file).Close
        
    file = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Second:

```
Sub open_and_copy_sheets()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim my_FileName As Variant
Dim nm As String
Dim nm2 As String
Dim i As Integer

nm = ActiveWorkbook.Name

my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")
If my_FileName <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName
End If

Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).Activate
nm2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name

For i = 1 To Workbooks(nm2).Worksheets.Count
      Sheets(i).Copy after:=Workbooks(nm).Sheets(Workbooks(nm).Sheets.Count)
Next i

Workbooks(nm2).Close SaveChanges:=False

Workbooks(nm).Activate
Worksheets(1).Activate

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be greately appreciated! I'm not that good in vba so any explanation would also be welcomed :)

Comment: Check on here, some questions about this type of thing exist already with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the function to be available in your PersonalWorkbook, then create a "Module" underneath your Personal.XLSB via the VBA Editor (see screen grab). I've fixed your code a little:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim destinationFile As Variant
    Dim sourceWbk As Workbook
    Dim destinationWbk As Workbook
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim index As Integer
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set sourceWbk = ActiveWorkbook
    
    destinationFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")
    
    If destinationFile <> False Then
        
        Workbooks.Open fileName:=destinationFile
        Set destinationWbk = ActiveWorkbook
        
        For Each sheet In sourceWbk.Sheets
          
          sheet.Copy Before:=destinationWbk.Sheets(index)
          index = index + 1
        
        Next sheet
        
        MsgBox (index & " sheets copied")
        
    Else
    
        MsgBox ("No file selected. Action aborted.")
        
    End If
    
    Set sheet = Nothing
    Set sourceWbk = Nothing
    Set destinationWbk = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

It's a little more compact than you had, which had one or two errors, also the code was continuing to attempt to copy even if no destination workbook was selected. You will just need to add a line to save the final new workbook (you could use the "index" variable to see if it is > 1 as a check to see if there is anything to save. "Option Explicit" is a good idea to have at the top of the module, it checks your code to make sure that any variable you use has explicitly been declared, which helps to avoid typing errors.
[image]

UPDATE HERE IS A COMPLETE SOLUTION:

You need to break this down into separate chunks to get what you want.

STEP 1 - Ask the user whether they are copying sheets to a single file or multiples:

```
    Public Function MasterCopy()

    Dim choice As Variant
    
    choice = InputBox("Enter S or M:", "Select whether to copy to a single or multiple sheets")
    
    Select Case UCase(choice)
        
        Case "S"
        
            Call FncSingleFileCopy
        
        Case "M"
        
            Call FncMultiFileCopy
            
        Case Else
        
            MsgBox ("Cancelled.")
            
    End Select
    
    
End Function
```

STEP 2: Add two functions, one for copying multiples and one for singles:

```
    Private Function FncMultiFileCopy()

    Dim destinationFile As Variant
    Dim sourceWbk As Workbook
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim copied As Integer
    
    Set sourceWbk = ActiveWorkbook
    
    folderPath = InputBox("Please paste the folder path", "Choose Folder")
    
    If (folderPath) <> "" Then
        
        folderPath = folderPath & "\"
        destinationFile = Dir(folderPath)

        Do While destinationFile <> ""
        
            If InStr(destinationFile, ".xls") > 1 Then
        
                Call FncCopySheets(sourceWbk, folderPath & destinationFile)
        
            End If
        
            destinationFile = Dir()
    
        Loop
        
        MsgBox ("Finished.")
        
    Else
    
        MsgBox ("Cancelled.")
        
    End If
    
    Set sourceWbk = Nothing
    
End Function

Private Function FncSingleFileCopy()

    Dim destinationFile As Variant
    Dim sourceWbk As Workbook
    Dim copied As Integer
    
    Set sourceWbk = ActiveWorkbook
    
    destinationFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")
    
    If destinationFile <> False Then
        
        copied = FncCopySheets(sourceWbk, destinationFile)
        
        MsgBox (copied & " sheets copied")
        
    Else
    
        MsgBox ("No file selected. Action aborted.")
        
    End If
    
    Set sourceWbk = Nothing
    
End Function
```

STEP 3: Finally, a function that takes a source workbook and destination file to copy the sheets, which can be called from either of the previous two functions:

```
    Private Function FncCopySheets(sourceWbk As Workbook, destinationFile As Variant) As Integer
    
    Dim destinationWbk As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim shtsCopied As Integer
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set destinationWbk = Workbooks.Open(destinationFile)
    
    For Each sht In sourceWbk.Sheets
          
        sht.Copy Before:=destinationWbk.Sheets(1)
        shtsCopied = shtsCopied + 1
        
    Next sht
        
    destinationWbk.Close (True)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    FncCopySheets = shtsCopied
    
    Set destinationWbk = Nothing
    
End Function
```

Comment: 0


Thank you for your answer an the time involved, i've ran your code and it gives me an error at 'sheet.Copy Before:=destinationWbk.Sheets(index)' . Also, as i saw, your code does not apply for multiple workbooks with multiple sheets.

Comment: So basically i need in my first code to replace 'folderpath = InputBox("Please paste the folder path", "Choose Folder") & "" file = Dir(folderpath)' with 'application.getopenfilename(multiselect:=true)' but then i don't know how to apply 'Workbooks.Open folderpath & file ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count) ActiveSheet.Name = Left(file, InStr(file, ".") - 1) Workbooks(file).Close' (which works fine for one workbook with one sheet) for each workbook selected and its sheets.

Comment: I have updated my answer. PS - No point telling me you get an error and not telling me what the error is!